# Class inside a lower package cannot access Main class, but class in same package as Main can

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As the title already says, for some reason IntelliJ cannot resolve the symbol "Main" in any classes within a package, meaning I cannot access it's static methods from these classes. However, a class that is on the same "level" as the Main class does recognize the Main class. Why is this?

I've already tried invalidating the caches and have checked and changed the Java SDK used, but to no use unfortunately.

Example:

```
Class Structure:
> src
  > Main
  > Test
  > A_Package
    > AnotherClass
```

Here, if Main has a static method called main(), the class Test is able to access it via Main.main(). However, putting Main.main() in the class AnotherClass inside the package A_Package will lead to IntelliJ saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'Main'."

Comment: Without seeing code, who knows?  But you do know that the default access is "package", right?  You have to explicitly mark classes/methods/fields as "public" to get wider access.

Comment: You should avoid placing classes in the “root” package - you can’t import the root package

Comment: it seems you missed to ```import Main``` inside the AnotherClass. However, having a subclass dependent on Main class is strange and may lead to spaghetti code.

Comment: Maybe just try menu "Build -> Rebuild Project" - sometimes IntelliJ is a bit confused. It happens.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Main class inside a package (which I also called Main), and the other classes are now able to import Main. Thanks @MadProgrammer